# why i cant change my value in this method

Tags: java, string

I confuse how to set "value", and here is the code
**strong text**

```
// Read from the database
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });


    value="hello";
```

when I set the "value" to "Hello", appear an error

Comment: First, when you encounter an error, post the full error message. Don't just say "I got an error" because your error could be one of thousands of things. Now for your code example... that's really how it looks? The String value is defined inside the event listener method, but you're setting value outside of the method, where it is undefined. You should edit your post to include the full error message, otherwise, we're just going to waste time guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Variable defined in a method only exists in the method. Read more about it in  [variable scope in java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `value` variable is inside `onDataChange`. This means that only code inside `onDataChange` can access it. You are trying to change the `value` variable from outside `onDataChange`.